# Need to fix left menu or div after some scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for the same left menu effect(as on following links) for my website. 

http://www.wiziq.com/contact/
http://juliusmattsson.com/
http://happycog.com/

Please let me know how i can fix div position after some scroll..

Thanks...

Comment: Another link :- http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/ (See the right Panel)

Comment: Which is your website.. What have you done until now?

Comment: Thanks for replying..i found good examples from "http://www.backslash.gr/content/blog/webdevelopment/6-navigation-menu-that-stays-on-top-with-jquery and http://www.gregjopa.com/2011/07/conditional-fixed-positioning-with-jquery/

Comment: for your left menu simply set style="position:fixed" , then it moves as your screen scrolls

Answer (score 0):

keep
   position:fixed
 in css do the following

```
ul
{
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 180px;
 position: fixed;
 border-top: solid 1px #D4DDE6;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```